# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

Tags: python-3.x

При попытке запустить `pip`

появляется ошибка:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

Необходимо установить pkg_resources. В интернете нашел такой способ: `sudo apt-get install pkg_ressources`
Но где и как это прописывать я не понял

Comment: Посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148284/5909792

Comment: Я смотрел. Проблема в том, что даже когда я пытаюсь написать в консоли только pip, Появляется эта ошибка

Comment: Интересно, а папка pkg_resources в папке питона находится?

Comment: Да, вот в этой папке: D:\Minicanoda3\Lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.0-py3.6.egg\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources

Comment: А что показывает `pip -V`?

Comment: Вообще воспользовавшись советом, прописать pip uninstall setuptools, затем pip install setuptools, получил эту проблему. Ответ был отмечен, как правильный...

Comment: from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'

Comment: Попробуйте скачать и запустить файл https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py

Comment: Приведите минимальный пример кода: `python3 -c 'import pkg_resources'` и покажите полный traceback. Покажите результат `python3 -mpip show setuptools`.  Копируйте команды/вывод как есть. Не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии, обновите ваш вопрос вместо этого. Нажмите [edit]

Comment: данная ошибка происходит при попытке через консоль написать pip...

Comment: python3 -mpip show setuptools. Куда нужно прописать в консоль?

Comment: в файле  bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py есть неустановленные библиотеки

Comment: ``sudo apt-get install pkg_ressources`` это для линукса.

Answer (score 1):

запуск файла `bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py` помог